# Android Firebase Dynamic Links setup - SHA-1 not recognized

Tags: android, firebase, sha1, firebase-dynamic-links

i am trying to setup my android app to use firebase dynamic links and am experiencing a problem in setting it up in the firebase console.

i had previously added my app to my firebase project to use the realtime database and it works with no isssues. i included the app's debug SHA-1 (which i obtained from the app-debug.apk).

now in the firebase dynamic links console screen, i can select my app from the drop-down list but it shows a warning in red "Please add SHA-1 for this Android app".

i even deleted the app from my firebase project and then added it again, also including the SHA-1 but i still get the red warning in the dynamic links console page when i select the app.

i'd appreciate any help in sorting this problem out (so that it recognizes the SHA-1).

note: i have 2 other apps which are included in my firebase project. one has a SHA-1 include and the other not. if i select these apps in the dynamic links console screen, the one with the SHA-1 selects with no warning message and the one without a SHA-1 displays (as expected) the warning message.

thanks

Comment: If you are sure you have added your sha1 to the app (package) you are trying to add a dynamic link to then I'd suggest that you file a ticket with support at firebase.google.com/support.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the SHA1 and SHA256 from your production certificate to firebase console

- Log into [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
- Select your firebase project, click on `Configuration`
- Find your Android App, then go to `SHA certificate fingerprints` and add both the SHA1 and SHA256 fingerprints for your production certificate.

To obtain the SHA1 and SHA256:

`keytool -list -v -keystore your_release_certificate.jks`

You should also add your debug SHA1 certificate, go to your project folder and execute

`./gradlew signingReport`

your debug SHA1 (and all of them) will look like this:

`8B:5F:27:7C:A6:59:9A:7C:BB:EF:2F:8B:17:A2:F6:1D:31:3B:73:E6`

Answer (score 3):

well, after doing NOTHING but trying again about 12 hours later, it's accepting the SHA-1. so i seems like firebase needs some time to process adding the SHA-1. IT WOULD BE NICE IF THEY INDICATED THAT WITH THEIR RED WARNING OF "Please add SHA-1 for this Android app". so annoying!

Comment: How did you include the SHA-1 key into the project?

Comment: in the firebase console i selected my app, then selected Manage for that app then selected Add Fingerprint. i then copied and pasted the SHA-1.- like i said, at first it did not work but the next day (after rebooting), it worked. so not sure if there is a delay on the firebase side or if my rebooting my laptop the next day had anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder where you install your Android Studio nd then jre->bin, for me its like that:

"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin"

Then open cmd/terminal their and type the following command

> ./keytool -list -v -keystore
> "C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey
> -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: You will need to change USERNAME to your actual username.