# Dynamic links creation on server return warning

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using the Firebase Dynamic Links REST API to create dynamic links on the server. The link is created but a warning is returned:

```
UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM: Android app '<package name>' lacks SHA256. AppLinks is not enabled for the app
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Checking with server team why we returning UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM when all params are recognized. Meanwhile ignore UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM word here, this message should be WARNING instead. I am checking about public docs for configuring Android AppLinks with FDL, it looks like we don't have such. Will update when find out more. In general: if the link works correctly with your Android App then feel free to ignore this warning.

Comment: Have a look at my answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902501/android-firebase-dynamic-links-setup-sha-1-not-recognized/). It may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Details about SHA256 warning https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#android-sha256-absent ; We are working to improve docs about this;

2) UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM is server bug, this is WARNING, fix coming;

EDIT Oct 13.

Usage of Firebase Dynamic Links usually have such distinct steps:

1. Create link;
2. Share and promote the link (aka get link to the hands of the customers/users);
3. Receive link in your iOS App, Android App or m-site.

Step #1 here can be done using Firebase Console, REST API https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest , iOS Builder API https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create, Android Builder API https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create , C++ API https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/cpp/create , Unity API https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/unity/create or manually https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually .

I believe you are using REST API from the question and comments.

During link creation process (or shortening the link) server may return errors or warnings that are related to #3 point (related to receiving the link). In your case if you are using Android App to receive the link, server returns Android related warnings.

Comment: We are not using this feature in an android app but on our server (JAVA)

Comment: So you do not have Android App in your Firebase project? Or you do not want to target Android App with this dynamic link? Please share your Firebase project and dynamic links you are creating. Feel free to open Firebase support ticket with this info.

Comment: I have an android and ios app in Firebase project but I want to create dynamic links on our server (JAVA)

Comment: The warning si returned by the link creation request (releted to #1). Anyways, is that a problem?

Comment: If links works correctly with your Android App (see step 3. Receive link in the answer) than this warning is not a problem.